# Reading/writing PostGIS layers with qgis_process-qgis command line tool

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-processing, command-line

How do I use the [qgis_process](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/standalone.html?highlight=qgis_process) command line tool with PostGIS layers as input and/or output?

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the connection string is:

```
"postgres://dbname=xxxx host=xxxx port=xxxx user=xxxx password=xxxx sslmode=xxxx table=\"schema\".\"tablename\" (geometry_column_name)"
```

Important is the usage of the backslash and quotation marks, the full string needs to be in double quotation marks and the schema and tablename as well, so you need to put a backslash in front of the (double) quotation marks around schema and tablename

Full commandline example to buffer osm roads with 100m, reading and writing the data from/to postgresql/postgis:

```
c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin> qgis_process-qgis.bat run native:buffer -- INPUT="postgres://dbname=xxxx host=xxxx port=xxxx user=xxxx password=xxxx sslmode=xxxx table=\"osm\".\"osm_roads\" (geom_epsg_3035)" DISTANCE=100 OUTPUT="postgres://dbname=xxxx host=xxxx port=xxxx user=xxxx password=xxxx sslmode=xxxx table=\"results\".\"osm_roads_100m\" (geom)"
```

when using pythons [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20system#os.system) to pass the command to the commandl line, it looks like:

```
os.system('''qgis_process-qgis.bat run native:buffer -- INPUT="postgres://dbname=xxxx host=xxxx port=xxxx user=xxxx password=xxxx sslmode=xxxx table=\\"osm\".\\"osm_roads\\" (geom_epsg_3035)" DISTANCE=100 OUTPUT="postgres://dbname=xxxx host=xxxx port=xxxx user=xxxx password=xxxx sslmode=xxxx table=\\"results\\".\\"osm_roads_100m\\" (geom)" ''')
```

note the double Backslash around schema and tablename

(I was running the code on windows 10 with qgis 3.20.3)